# Migrate Product Backlog Items from TFS 2012 to TFS 2017

Tags: tfs

what is the best way of migrating PBI and associated items from TFS 2012 instance into TFS 2017 instance?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just upgrade your server?

Answer (score 0):

You could try [OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1455028.OpsHubVisualStudioOnlineMigrationUtility), the free version supports migrate work items with attachments, comments and link traceability:

[image]